# Show that all lines are Borel sets and have Lebesgue measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Problem: Show that all lines $\ell$ are in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{k})$, $k \geq 2$, and have Lebesgue measure $\lambda_k(\ell)=0$. [First show that any line segment is in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{k})$. Then write a line as an increasing limit of line segments and use the appropriate continuity result.]

My approach would be to show that any $\ell$ is related to some $\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}^{k-1}$ [or any line segment to some closed set $[a,b] \times \{0\}^{k-1}$] by linear transformation and translation. By closedness of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{k})$ w.r.t. these operations, $\ell \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{k})$. By invariance of the Lebesgue measure w.r.t. these operations,  $\lambda_k(\ell) = 0$.

However, I take this exercise from a book, where the exercise is located right at the beginning of the chapter on Lebesgue measures, before linear transformations and translations are treated. So I wonder whether there is a more fundamental way to solve it?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line segment of length $1$ can be covered by closed cubes of sidelength
$1/N$ centred at the points $x_0,\ldots,x_N$ equally spaced between the endpoints $x_0$ and $x_N$. So it's contained in a set of outer measure
$\le (N+1)/N^k$ for any positive integer $N$. That's enough to show the
segment has measure zero.